# UnCheck radio buttens by JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

i have a Question application...each Questions have 4 options...
i need to Uncheck other options when select a option in each question...
please help me i have no time...
this script change all question options UnCheck...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html data-bs-theme="light" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/TemplateExam/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css?h=fe7fdfec700d100dc745dc64d3600cb2">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/TemplateExam/assets/css/styles.min.css?h=d5d4a12a0f08968858f8860faa01866f">
</head>
<body style="/*background-color: #9dffa1;*/">
    <div class="justify-content-end text-end disabled"></div>
    <form method="post" action="">
        @foreach (var item in Questions)
        {
            <div class="question" id="@item.QuestionID">
                <!-- Start: List Group With Checkboxes -->
                <legend dir="rtl">@item.QuestionText</legend>
                <ul class="list-group" style="direction: rtl;margin-left: 2rem;">
                    <li class="list-group-item" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #009e49 0%, #efea07 100%);">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input value="@item.QuestionID" name="QuestionID" hidden />
                            <label><input type="radio" id="@($"Option1_{item.QuestionID}")" data-question-id="@item.QuestionID" value="@item.Option1" class="answer" name="Options">@item.Option1</label>
                            <label><input type="radio" id="@($"Option2_{item.QuestionID}")" data-question-id="@item.QuestionID" value="@item.Option2" class="answer" name="Options">@item.Option2</label>
                            <label><input type="radio" id="@($"Option3_{item.QuestionID}")" data-question-id="@item.QuestionID" value="@item.Option3" class="answer" name="Options">@item.Option3</label>
                            <label><input type="radio" id="@($"Option4_{item.QuestionID}")" data-question-id="@item.QuestionID" value="@item.Option4" class="answer" name="Options">@item.Option4</label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <!-- End: List Group With Checkboxes -->
            </div>
            <br />
        }
        <button type="submit" class="text-center">اتمام آزمون</button>
    </form>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.answer').change(function () {
                var questionID = $(this).data('question-id');
                $('input[type=radio][data-question-id="' + questionID + '"]').not(this).prop('checked', false);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean.  Is this related to the server-side technologies used, or is the problem entirely in client-side code?  Can you update the code in the question to a [mcve] as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193) which demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Hey, I don't think you actually need the script as radio buttons with the same `name` attribute should, from memory, only allow one to be selected at a time. Try removing the script and seeing if it works then.

Comment: @DanP that's *literally* the whole point in using radios

Comment: Your issue (with radios, remove your code as above) is with `style="direction: rtl` this is changing how the radio option `o` is appearing "next" to the `<label>` that it's nested in.

Comment: I also tried using `<label for=` but a quick check didn't help: https://jsfiddle.net/z15fxtjy/1/

Comment: To keep your radio bullet and label text together, you need to wrap them in a `div` (`display:inline-block`) otherwise the `rtl` on the parent messes up the display, making it *look like* your radios don't match the labels.   https://jsfiddle.net/z15fxtjy/2/

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the issue and from what I can see in your code, the issue is that you have radio buttons for each question and they all have the same value in the name attribute of the input element (`name="Options"`). Therefor you can only select one option for all questions in the same form.

Radio buttons are grouped by their name and only one radio button can be selected in each group. Give the radion buttons for each question a unique name, like `name="question_1"` etc.

```css
fieldset {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form name="form01">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Question 1?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="question_1">Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="question_1">Option 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="3" name="question_1">Option 3</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Question 2?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="question_2">Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="question_2">Option 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="3" name="question_2">Option 3</label>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Question 3?</legend>
    <label><input type="radio" value="1" name="question_3">Option 1</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="2" name="question_3">Option 2</label>
    <label><input type="radio" value="3" name="question_3">Option 3</label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: I concur - didn't notice the `for` loop initially - would have been obvious if OP ever provided the *rendered* HTML.  Each "group" of answers needs it own `name=`.

Answer (score 0):

If all radio buttons for different questions have the same `name` attribute (`Options`), then only one `option` can be selected across all questions because radio buttons with the same `name` attribute are treated as part of the same group, and only one `option` can be selected within a group.

To resolve this issue, you need to ensure that each group of radio buttons for each question has a unique `name` attribute. Typically, you would generate unique name attributes dynamically based on the question ID or another identifier.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="question" id="@item.QuestionID">
        <!-- Start: List Group With Checkboxes -->
        <legend dir="rtl">@item.QuestionText</legend>
        <ul class="list-group" style="direction: rtl;margin-left: 2rem;">
            <li class="list-group-item" style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #009e49 0%, #efea07 100%);">
                <div class="form-check">
                    <input value="@item.QuestionID" name="QuestionID" hidden />
                    <label><input type="radio" id="@($"Option1_{item.QuestionID}")" data-question-id="@item.QuestionID" value="@item.Option1" class="answer" name="@($"Options_{item.QuestionID}")">@item.Option1</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" id="@($"Option2_{item.QuestionID}")" data-question-id="@item.QuestionID" value="@item.Option2" class="answer" name="@($"Options_{item.QuestionID}")">@item.Option2</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" id="@($"Option3_{item.QuestionID}")" data-question-id="@item.QuestionID" value="@item.Option3" class="answer" name="@($"Options_{item.QuestionID}")">@item.Option3</label>
                    <label><input type="radio" id="@($"Option4_{item.QuestionID}")" data-question-id="@item.QuestionID" value="@item.Option4" class="answer" name="@($"Options_{item.QuestionID}")">@item.Option4</label>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- End: List Group With Checkboxes -->
    </div>
    <br />
}
```